# How can I get certain columns from datatable to datagridview?

Tags: c#

I have a datatable that I want to extract certain information from (only certain rows and only certain columns).  I'm trying to use the code below, but I'm getting an index out of range error when I run it, and I'm not sure if what I'm doing is the best way to get only certain data from a datatable to a datagridview.  Any ideas?

```
        currentRow = 0;
        int dataGridRow = 0;
        foreach (DataRow row in resultsDT.Rows)
        {
            string value = resultsDT.Rows[currentRow]["HighLow"].ToString();
            if (value.Equals("High") | value.Equals("Low"))
            {
                dataGridView2.Rows[dataGridRow].Cells["colHighLow"].Value = resultsDT.Rows[currentRow]["HighLow"];
                dataGridView2.Rows[dataGridRow].Cells["colDifference"].Value = resultsDT.Rows[currentRow]["Difference"];
                dataGridView2.Rows[dataGridRow].Cells["colMbrSep"].Value = resultsDT.Rows[currentRow]["MBRSEP"];
                dataGridView2.Rows[dataGridRow].Cells["colLocation"].Value = resultsDT.Rows[currentRow]["LOCATION"];
                dataGridView2.Rows[dataGridRow].Cells["colDistrict"].Value = resultsDT.Rows[currentRow]["DIST"];
                dataGridView2.Rows[dataGridRow].Cells["colAddress"].Value = resultsDT.Rows[currentRow]["ADDR1"];
                dataGridView2.Rows[dataGridRow].Cells["colMeter"].Value = resultsDT.Rows[currentRow]["METER"];
                dataGridView2.Rows[dataGridRow].Cells["colKWh"].Value = resultsDT.Rows[currentRow]["KWH"];
                dataGridRow++;
            }
            currentRow++;
        }
```

Comment: How many rows dataGridView2 contains?

Comment: Does at least sucessfully put a value int the grid, or fails in the very begining ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can only guess what you need is

```
   currentRow = 0;
        int dataGridRow = 0;
        foreach (DataRow row in resultsDT.Rows)
        {
            string value = resultsDT.Rows[currentRow]["HighLow"].ToString();
            if (value.Equals("High") | value.Equals("Low"))
            {
                //THIS LINE
                dataGridView2.Rows.Add();

                dataGridView2.Rows[dataGridRow].Cells["colHighLow"].Value = resultsDT.Rows[currentRow]["HighLow"];
                dataGridView2.Rows[dataGridRow].Cells["colDifference"].Value = resultsDT.Rows[currentRow]["Difference"];
                dataGridView2.Rows[dataGridRow].Cells["colMbrSep"].Value = resultsDT.Rows[currentRow]["MBRSEP"];
                dataGridView2.Rows[dataGridRow].Cells["colLocation"].Value = resultsDT.Rows[currentRow]["LOCATION"];
                dataGridView2.Rows[dataGridRow].Cells["colDistrict"].Value = resultsDT.Rows[currentRow]["DIST"];
                dataGridView2.Rows[dataGridRow].Cells["colAddress"].Value = resultsDT.Rows[currentRow]["ADDR1"];
                dataGridView2.Rows[dataGridRow].Cells["colMeter"].Value = resultsDT.Rows[currentRow]["METER"];
                dataGridView2.Rows[dataGridRow].Cells["colKWh"].Value = resultsDT.Rows[currentRow]["KWH"];
                dataGridRow++;
            }
            currentRow++;
        }
```